# Why isn't the miracle of Channukah mentioned in Selichot?

Tags: tefilla, chanuka, selichot, miracle

In the selichot service, we have a prayer which lists the historic times when Hashem answered prayers (even implicit ones). The "mi she'ana" prayer starts with Avraham on Har Hamoriah and moves forward in time until the story of Purim and then the catch all "kol hatzaddikim..."

According to the Artscroll commentary, the prayer is centered around 7 historical events but has been expanded to the current list of 20. But among the various miraculous events, the entire story of Channukah is not found.

Why would the story of Channukah not merit inclusion in the expanded form? I know that it is beyond the scope in terms of time, but was there an established "closing" date for the writing of this piece? Is it because the story is not biblically canonical?

I know that there are too many miracles for each to be mentioned, but Channukah has a position in our yearly celebrations and is a miracle (be it of oil, or military might) which we commemorate. Why is it absent from this litany?

Comment: I would guess that it goes through the anshei knesses hagedolah which was before the second temple. That was the end of prophesy and of open miracles. Additionally, the Chashmonaim led to the Romans and the destruction of the second Temple.

Comment: @sabbahillel the original 7 events are recorded in the gemara, meaning that the rest were added afterwards and the gemara was written down after the Anshei Knesset, so there were additions made. And if Channukah is not a miracle, why is "al hanisim" attached to it?

Comment: The miracle of Channuka was the oil. That is not a Yeshua. Although they won the war, it wasn't without casualties. That was not an open intervention that would fit the list of answered prayers.

Comment: @HaLeiVi that seems to be a subjective line to draw. We proclaim this oil-miracle as an open one, significant and worth commemoration. We have no holiday signifying the resting of the prophetic spirit on Elisha. Is it that oil-miracle wasn't the result of prayer? If so, that adds a strange dimension to Channukah.

Comment: The idea is not to commemorate miracles. We are invoking the Middah of how Hashem responded to a Tefilla. Channukah was a great display of favor, which is why we celebrate it. But it wasn't about a Tefillah being answered. What stands out is their Mesiras Nefesh. Tefillah is not a central theme in the sort of Channukah.

Comment: But there is merit to the concept of referring only to biblical events. We find in other seats areas that we use Pesukim exclusively. We don't mention Rebbe Chiya and sons being answered instantly for rain.

Comment: understood, but the three thrown into the furnace didn't pray -- they were saved by dint of willingness to die. I have to think about a followup question about the nature of Channukah and favor as opposed to prayer.